# not giving value after decimal point

Tags: javascript

This method gives me wrong value, why? Result must be `5.088100` but it gives me `5.o88100` in any value. If the first number after decmal point is zero then it removes it, why?

```
var precision = descriptor.digits ? descriptor.digits[1] : 2;

var int_part = Math.floor(value);

var dec_part = Math.abs(Math.floor((value % 1) * Math.pow(10, precision)));
```

Comment: Where does the letter `o` come from? You're only using math functions...

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  Pleas post more code, perhaps the exact example you are quoting?  You seem to be implying that something changes `5.088100` into `5.o88100`?  So something is replaing a `0` for a `o`?

Comment: ry it was typing mistake.there was nothing no(0)or no (o).

Answer (score 3):

Because you're turning the part after the decimal point into an integer, so `08` becomes `8` — just like `var dec_part = 08` would give you `8`.

If you want the decimal part use string manipulation:

```
var tmp = value.toFixed(precision).split("."),
    int_part = tmp[0],
    dec_part = tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you treat the `dec_part` as a number, if absolutely clear that the leading zeroes are droped off. numbers don't and can't have leading zeros.

what you're really trying to do is getting the two parts as strings, wich is a lot easier using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split):

```
var parts = value.split(".");
var int_part = parts[0],
var dec_part = parts[1];
```

but at least, if you just want to round your `value` to a specific precision, you can just drop that complicated stuff out and use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
value = value.toFixed(precision);
```